# Android Fragments or Layouts - advice needed

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am developing an application which should display a number of tiles on the first page. Tiles are generated dynamically from json, each should allocate itself according to size specified in json and should take as much screen as required. Each tile represents short summary of information. The requirement is that when tile is pressed user is redirected to another page which provides more detailed info (like a form) which takes the whole page. User then should be able to go back to previous page and choose another tile if needed or go back to the first one. I don't know in advance how many tiles there will be and what are their components, so everything is dynamic. There is also a possibility that small tiles(with different info) can be required to be drawn on detailed view.

At the moment I am on the stage where all small tiles are displayed on the first page and I need to find the best way to display detailed view and allow user to navigate easily and quickly. Each tile extends RelativeLayout because of absolute positioning of components inside. I am considering switching tiles from Layout to Fragments because they seem to be providing flexibility required and many articles and tutorials I search refer to them. In this case when user presses the tile fragment, all existing tiles would be replaced with required detail fragment. Pressing back button would replace detail fragment with previous smaller ones on the screen (would it be display all of them or only one?).

Another option I am considering is to leave layouts and on tile press redirect user to a separate Activity with detail view. In this case navigating back seems to be destroying activity and it will need to be redrawn again if user wants to come back to it (redraw is not desirable).

My question is **what is better for performance**. Each tile as well as detail view might have some images in it and full page will take time to load. But figuring out how to handle this with Fragments programmatically might take a while and the last thing I want to find is that Fragments are not suitable. Maybe you have other ideas for scenario described? Any good tutorials/articles where Fragments are created and managed programmatically completely(no XML).
I am relatively new to Android and completely lost now.

Edit:
Thanks everyone for your advice. I can't choose the best answer at this point. I have to do some more research and learning now. Will do that later.

Comment: "Each tile as well as detail view might have some images in it and full page will take time to load" - you might consider optimizing it, like caching values - like writing to sd card if its huge data. On android your activity (no matter if fragment or not) might get destroyed any time, you must be prepared to quickly show it again.

Comment: Certainly, this is something to be considered and done. But at the moment I am trying to solve another issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you have described above you do not need Fragments to do this. On your main page you can use a [GridView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html) to display your tiles. You could create two other Activities. One called TileActivity which will open each time a tile is pressed. Then you could create a PopulateActivity which would populate the TileActivity with the relevant information depending on which Tile was pressed. In terms of performance instead of closing the TileActivity to go back to the main page you could use [Intent Flags](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) so that the TileActivity isn't closed it is just added to the stack and then restarted instead of recreated each time its called.

Comment: I've selected this answer because I managed to implement this functionality without using fragments. I will definitely need them for some custom components, but in this case I associate required model which needs to be rendered in the detailed view with every tile; when user presses this tile, I used Parcealable for models and can send it with the Intent to the next page.

Answer (score 2):

Fragment should be the best way to go. because filling details in a fragment dynamically is easy. will help check some codes i have written that could solve this

Comment: Voted you up because you were offering your help in coding.

Answer (score 2):

Fragments are a new style in Android for creating GUIs, they should not be compared with simple Activity + xml layout's in performance terms. Fragments were created to make it easier to build complicated GUIs, on both phones and tablets. You can create low performance GUI using both methods.

From your description I suppose its best to create two fragments, and wire them in Master Detail pattern. Master will be your json list with short summaries, and detail will be your additional data fragment. You can still put both fragments in separate activities, and show detail fragment from master one (master actitity will get hidden) - this makes sense on small screen devices. But you can show both fragments on one screen on tablets. See 'Master Detail Flow Template', http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/templates.html.

So fragments gives you a lot of flexibility to modify your UI, without huge code rewrites.

Some new widgets like ViewPager will work only with fragments, so if you want to use it you better invest time in learning them.